# What is the best way to do cluster analysis for geocode/(lat/long) datapoints in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, geo

What is the best way to do cluster analysis for geocode/(lat/long) datapoints in python?

I have preformed a K-means clustering analysis, but I am aware this is probably not the best way to perform a clustering analysis for lat/long data points. 
I did this through sci-kit learn, furthermore the centroid lat/longs that were produced did not equal the mean of all points within each cluster label.

I have also tried using DBscan, but I believe that is not the best tool to perform a clustering analysis based on my dataset.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Also, the purpose of this analysis is to divide the locations into any number of zones or clusters.... this is why k-means was my first approach. all points must be assigned to a cluster.

Comment: You should have a look to specific spatial analysis clustering algorithms like Automated Zoning Procedure (AZP) or max *p* regions model.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can calculate the distance matrix for your points and then use any clustering algorithm: K-Means, DBSCAN, and so on.

You can also try [GVM](http://www.tomgibara.com/clustering/fast-spatial/) - the fast spatial clustering algorithm.